# Proving an element is of order n.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

This is a question from my final exam in Algebra. Could someone please verify if it's correct. If not, could you please point out where it falls apart? Don't answer it for me! I forgot exactly how my professor stated it, but it's more or less this:

Let $G$ be a group. Let $g \in G$ be an element of order $n$. Let $h \in G$. Prove that $h^{-1}gh \in G$ is of order $n$.

*Proof*. By the definition of the order of an element, $g^n = e$. Note that since $h \in G$, there exists an inverse of $h$, i.e., $h^{-1} \in G$ because $G$ is a group . We want to show that $(h^{-1}gh)^n = e$. Then,

$$(h^{-1}gh)^n = (h^{-n})(g^n)(h^n) = (h^{-n})(h^n) = (h^{-1}h)^n =e^n = e.$$

Hence, $|h^{-1}gh| = n$. $\tag*{$\square$}$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You've shown that $(h^{-1}gh)^n=e$, but not that there is no smaller integer that could be the order.

Comment: @AshwinTrisal Crap! Well, you live and you learn.

Comment: Also... in writing $(h^{-1}gh)^n = h^{-n}g^nh^n$, are you assuming that $h$ and $g$ commute? Be more careful there, that statement is not true in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One must also show that $n$ is the *smallest* integer to satisfy $(h^{-1}gh)^x = e$.  To do this, suppose $\text{ord}(h^{-1}gh) = m$ for some $m < n$.  This means $(h^{-1}gh)^m = h^{-1}g^mh = e$.

See the contradiction?

Comment: Yes, I do, $g^m \neq e$. So the order has to be $n$. I wish you didn't complete the argument for me. By the time I started reading, it was too late. Regardless, thank you very much!

Comment: Ah, sorry about that @CuriousMathStudent!

Comment: No need to be sorry. Happy holidays!

Comment: @CuriousMathStudent See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/658088/242) for a slightly more general perspective (which makes it obvious).